# Why do we need to explicitly cast the optional to Any?

Tags: swift, casting, option-type

According to Apple Doc,

> The Any type represents values of any type, including optional types.
>   Swift gives you a warning if you use an optional value where a value
>   of type Any is expected. If you really do need to use an optional
>   value as an Any value, you can use the as operator to explicitly cast
>   the optional to Any, as shown below.

```
var things = [Any]()
things.append(3)                     // No warning
let optionalNumber: Int? = 3
things.append(optionalNumber)        // Warning, even though Any also represents optional types.
things.append(optionalNumber as Any) // No warning
```

Why do we need to explicitly cast the optional to `Any`?

Comment: The explicit coercion to `Any` just silences the warning, nothing more. You get the warning because erasing an optional to `Any` is often undesirable as it's difficult to get the optionality back.

Comment: @Hamish Why it's difficult to get the optionality back? I mean why the value can't be cast back from Any to an Int optional?

Comment: @RobertDresler The link you mentioned suggests a way out. It does not explain the underlying cause. My question is different:

Any type represents values of any type, including optional types. But still, there is a need to cast the optional to Any.  Why? Why there is no need to cast the Int value to Any on the other hand?

Comment: @Damon It can, but it currently [requires some erasing trickery](https://forums.swift.org/t/get-value-after-assigning-string-any-to-string-any/10595/3?u=hamishknight) to let the runtime perform the cast. Although as Rob points out, `[Any]` is almost certainly the wrong type to be using here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every type can be implicitly promoted to an optional of that type. This means that when you cast `T?` to `Any` it is very hard to know whether it was originally `T` or originally `T?` (or even `T??` or worse). Most confusing is that `Any` can be promoted to `Any?` and that `Any?` is of type `Any`, so telling the difference between `Any`, `Any?`, `Any??`, and `Any???` (etc.) is very tricky, and sometimes impossible.

`Any` is a very tricky type in Swift and should almost never be used. Except for explicitly tricking the compiler (in some very fancy and fragile type-eraser), I don't know of any case where it really makes sense to have `Any` as a variable type, and definitely not in the form of `[Any]`. If you're created an `[Any]`, you've gone down a bad path that isn't going to go well.

There are a very few cases where `Any` as a function parameter type makes sense (`print()` being the most famous), but they are extremely rare in app-level code. If you find yourself needing `Any`, you've probably done something wrong, and the compiler is going to fuss at you about it and often make you write extra `as` code to make sure you really mean the messy things you're saying.

Just to give some concrete versions of this, optionality tends to be lost when you enter `Any`. So consider this situation:

```
let number: Int = 3
let optionalNumber: Int? = 3
let nilNumber: Int? = nil

let anyNumber = number as Any
let anyOptional = optionalNumber as Any
let anyNil = nilNumber as Any

if anyNumber is Int { print("number is Int")} // yes
if anyOptional is Int { print("optional number is Int")} // yes
if anyNil is Int { print("nil is Int")} // no

if anyNil is Int? { print("nil is Int?")}
// -> Error: Cannot downcast from 'Any' to a more optional type 'Int?'
```

Rats.

We can't get our optional back the same way we put it in. We can promote it of course:

```
if (anyNil as Any?) is Int? { print("nil is Int?") }  // yes
```

But we can promote anything that way, since everything is implicitly an optional of itself:

```
if (anyNumber as Any?) is Int? { print("number is Int?")}  // also yes
```

So, um. Rats. We don't really know if it was originally optional or not. It's mess, and the compiler is warning you that it's going to be a mess if you go very far down this road. T->Any is a bit of magic. T->T? is also a bit of magic. Combine the two magics, and you had better know exactly what you're doing.